# how to access h2 console of a spring-boot app deployed in K8S cluster and exposed through Ingress component

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, h2, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Spring boot Application deployed in the K8S cluster, which is being exposed using the ingress component. I am using the h2 database for testing purposes in one of the environments (review env) and want to access the h2 console for the deployed spring boot application. I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried appending the h2 DB console address to my app ingress endpoint like *http://myapp.com/h2-console*, but I have no luck here, any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show a reproducible example of your current status, please?

Comment: @rok I am doing it on my enterprise code base right now so won't be able to provide the reproducible code, but I'll try to reproduce the same problem on my personal repo and will share the same. Thanks :)